# How to use RankBoost Bipartite for training multiple queries (each query has different set of relevant and irrelevant doc)

Tags: machine-learning, information-retrieval

I'm referring this paper - An Efficient Boosting Algorithm for Combining Preferences(http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/jmlr/papers/volume4/freund03a/freund03a.pdf)
And implementing 3.3 - An efficient implementation for bipartite feedback.

Now I'm confused with distribution v when I have data from more than one queries - e.g. Q1 returns some doc (A,B,C) out of(A ... Z) as 1(Relevant) and other as 0, Q2 returns (D, N, V) as relevant. Hence different X0 and X1 set for different query.
Hence confused with initialization of V update of V, and calculating potential(pi). If anyone can suggest something that would be great.

EDIT:

I was thinking to make distribution (v of x0 and x1) for all queries such that it sums up to 1.0, and update distribution similar way ... please share your thoughts!

EDIT2:
If anyone is coming here then EDIT1 works!

Comment: @BalusC ok, done edit!